Bogachev Lifting Theorem (Measure Theory 10.5.4)
I am reading the proof of theorem 10.5.4 in Bogachev's Measure Theory, and I'm stuck at a point:

$\textbf{10.5.4. Theorem.}$ For every complete probability measure $\mu$, there exists a lifting on $\mathcal L^{\infty}(\mu)$.

$\text{PROOF.} \, $ We consider the set $\mathcal{M}$ consisting of all pairs $(\mathcal{E}, L)$, where $\mathcal{E}$ is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra in $\mathcal{A}$ containing the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}_0$ generated by all measure zero sets and $L$ is a lifting on $\mathcal{E}$. The set $\mathcal{M}$ is not empty, since on $\mathcal{A}_0$ one has the lifting $L_0$ defined as follows: $L_0(I_A) = 0$ if $\mu(A) = 0$, $L_0(I_A) = 1$ if $\mu(A) = 1$. The set $\mathcal{M}$ is equipped with the following order: $(\mathcal{E}_1, L_1) \leq (\mathcal{E}_2, L_2)$ if $\mathcal{E}_1 \subset \mathcal{E}_2$ and $L_2|_{\mathcal{E}_1} = L_1$. We show that $\mathcal{M}$ contains a maximal element. By Zorn's lemma it suffices to verify that every linearly ordered part $\{(\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}, L_{\alpha})\}$ in $\mathcal{M}$ has an upper bound. Let $\mathcal{E}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by all $\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}$. We shall construct on $\mathcal{E}$ a lifting $L$ whose restriction to $\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}$ is $L_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha$. Then the pair $(\mathcal{E}, L)$ will be an upper bound.

Suppose first that for every sequence $(\mathcal{E}_{\alpha_n}, L_{\alpha_n})$ in $\mathcal{M}$ one has an upper bound $(\mathcal{E}_{\beta}, L_{\beta})$ in $\mathcal{M}$. Then $L$ can be defined in the following way. It is easy to see that for every $\mathcal{E}$-measurable bounded function $f$, there exists a countable collection of indices $\alpha_n$ such that $f$ is measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by all $\mathcal{E}_{\alpha_n}$. We take $\beta$ with $(\mathcal{E}_{\alpha_n}, L_{\alpha_n}) \leq (\mathcal{E}_{\beta}, L_{\beta})$ for all $n$ and set $L(f) = L_{\beta}(f)$. It is readily verified that due to the linear ordering of the considered collection, $L$ is well-defined. It is clear that $L$ is a lifting. Suppose now that our assumption is false for some sequence $(\mathcal{E}_{\alpha_n}, L_{\alpha_n})$. It is clear that this sequence can be taken as increasing. Since for every $\alpha$, there exists $n$ with $(\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}, L_{\alpha}) \leq (\mathcal{E}_{\alpha_n}, L_{\alpha_n})$ because otherwise $\alpha_n \leq \alpha$ for all $n$, we obtain that $\mathcal{E}$ is generated by an increasing sequence of $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{E}_{\alpha_n}$. By Theorem $10.2.3$, for every bounded $\mathcal{E}$-measurable function $f$, almost everywhere there exists a limit $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{E}^{\mathcal{E}_n} f(x)$ and this limit equals $f(x)$ a.e. By means of this we define a lifting $L_0$. To this end, as in the case of the interval, $[\ldots]$

I don't understand why he says that $L$ is well-defined and is a lifting. I mean, let's suppose that we have $(\mathcal{E}_\beta,L_\beta)$ and $(\mathcal{E}_{\beta '},L_{\beta '})$ such that they are both upper bounds of $(\mathcal{E}_{\alpha_n},L_{\alpha_n})$. How can we conclude that $L_{\beta}(f)=L_{\beta '}(f)$? We only know that $L_{\beta}(\varphi)=L_{\beta '}(\varphi)$ for every $\varphi$ that is $\mathcal{E}_{\alpha_n}$-measurable for some $n$, but $f$ is not one of these. So what am I missing?
Just to be clear, a lifting is a map $L:\mathcal{L}^\infty(\mu)\rightarrow \mathcal{L}^\infty(\mu)$ such that:

$L(f)=f$ $\mu$-a.e.
If $f=g$ $\mu$-a.e. then $L(f)(x)=L(g)(x)$ for every $x\in X$
If $f=1$ $\mu$-a.e. then $L(f)(x)=1$ for every $x\in X$
$L(\alpha f+\beta g)(x)=\alpha L(f)(x)+\beta L(g)(x)$ for every $x\in X$
$L(fg)(x)=L(f)(x)L(g)(x)$ for every $x\in X$

Edit: My main idea is focused on the fact that, if given $f$ that is $\sigma (\mathcal{E}_n)$-measurable, there exists $\varphi$ that is $\mathcal{E}_n$-measurable for some $n$ and $\varphi=f$ $\mu$-a.e., then I have the conclusion using property 2. of liftings, but this doesn't seem a plausible statement, so I don't know what to do.

It seems Bogachev tried to modify the proof of Theorem 1 from this paper. In my opinion, the proof from that paper is a lot simpler and more believable than what Bogachev is doing.

@P.P.Tuong yes this paper is more clear, and I also found other papers with more or less the same technique: from what I understand, the fact is that the $(\mathcal{E}\beta,L\beta)$ considered by Bogachev is part of the linearly ordered set ${(\mathcal{E}\alpha,L\alpha)}$ and is not a generic element of $\mathcal{M}$, and this obviously gives the good definition as it stated. Probably is simply not clear in the way Bogachev wrote it.

@LuigiTraino I too thought $\beta$ was supposed to be one of the $\alpha$, but it's not always possible to choose $\beta$ that way: it's not possible for example when ${(\mathcal E_{\alpha_n},L_{\alpha_n})}$ is cofinal in ${(\mathcal E_\alpha,L_\alpha)}$ and ${(\mathcal E_\alpha,L_\alpha)}$ doesn't have a maximal element.

@P.P.Tuong I cut out a part of the proof, in which he basically supposes that there is a cofinal family ${(\mathcal{E}{\alpha_n},L{\alpha_n})}$. I edited the post and inserted also that part of the proof. As I said, the phrasing is still misleading to me, but it seems to me that our guessing is correct
